Non standard evalution inside purrr::map
I am trying to learn how to use NSE inside purrr (& dplyr) functions.
Case 1) has "defused" group variable and it works. Case 2) has "defused" numerical variable and it DOESN'T work. I cannot quite understand the warning message "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA".
Here is a reproducible example:
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# CASE 1) works!
group_var <- c("gender", "species")
 
NSE_map_g <- map(.x = group_var, 
                             .f = ~{
                                starwars %>% 
                                    group_by( {{.x}}) %>% 
                                    summarise(mean_height  = mean(height  , na.rm = TRUE ))
                             })

pluck(NSE_map_g,1)

Here is the problematic case:
# CASE 2) DOESN'T work!
num_var <- c("height", "birth_year")
 
NSE_map_n <- map(.x = num_var, 
                      .f = ~{
                        starwars %>% 
                            group_by(species) %>% 
                            summarise("mean_{{.x}}"  := mean({{.x}}, na.rm = TRUE ))
                      })

pluck(NSE_map_n,1)


You could wrap num_var with syms: .x = syms(num_var) should work.

I think this gives you what you want.  You need to give map a vector of symbols, not characters.
NSE_map_n <- map(.x = vars(height, birth_year), 
                 .f = ~{
                   starwars %>% 
                     group_by(species) %>% 
                     summarise("mean_{{.x}}" := mean({{.x}}, na.rm = TRUE ))
                 })

NSE_map_n
[[1]]
# A tibble: 38 × 2
   species   mean_height
   <chr>           <dbl>
 1 Aleena            79 
 2 Besalisk         198 
 3 Cerean           198 
 4 Chagrian         196 
 5 Clawdite         168 
 6 Droid            131.
 7 Dug              112 
 8 Ewok              88 
 9 Geonosian        183 
10 Gungan           209.
# ℹ 28 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 38 × 2
   species   mean_birth_year
   <chr>               <dbl>
 1 Aleena              NaN  
 2 Besalisk            NaN  
 3 Cerean               92  
 4 Chagrian            NaN  
 5 Clawdite            NaN  
 6 Droid                53.3
 7 Dug                 NaN  
 8 Ewok                  8  
 9 Geonosian           NaN  
10 Gungan               52  
# ℹ 28 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

You can get something similar, using what is (to my mind at least) simpler logic with:
starwars %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(height, birth_year), ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 38 × 3
   species   height birth_year
   <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 Aleena       79       NaN  
 2 Besalisk    198       NaN  
 3 Cerean      198        92  
 4 Chagrian    196       NaN  
 5 Clawdite    168       NaN  
 6 Droid       131.       53.3
 7 Dug         112       NaN  
 8 Ewok         88         8  
 9 Geonosian   183       NaN  
10 Gungan      209.       52  
# ℹ 28 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


NSE often breaks my understanding of R. In this case: Shouldn't it be rlang::exprs(height, birth_year) instead of dplyr::vars()?

@MartinGal: "NSE often breaks my understanding of R.": you are not alone!  In this case, both versions work.  dplyr::vars was my first attempt and I didn't explore further.  Looking deeper now... vars is simply a wrapper for rlang::quos.  The bodies and signatures of rlang::quos and rlang::exprs appear to be identical.  So the calls are, I believe, equivalent.

Thanks @MartinGal and @Limey (I know this is unnecessarily convoluted, but I wanted to generalize the function). Indeed this is what I was looking for:
num_var <- c("height", "birth_year")
 
NSE_map_n <-  map(
    # .x = num_var,       # WRONG, (vector of characters)
    # .x = {{num_var}},   # WRONG but why ??
    .x = !! sym(num_var), # RIGHT, (list of symbols)  
    .f = ~{
        starwars %>% 
            group_by(species) %>% 
            summarise("mean_{{.x}}" := mean({{.x}}, na.rm = TRUE ))
    })

I had not seen the rlang::sym() function which is explained here under Names patterns - Symbolise and inject.
I still don't get why {{ was enough in CASE 1) for the group_var, but not in CASE 2) for num_var.
